# How to remove Button/view from all the items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a basic horizontal recyclerView which has buttons in all the items. When user clicks a button in any one of the items, I want the button to be removed or visibility to be gone from all the items in recyclerView.

This is my Code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        v.postDelayed(() -> holder.likes.setVisibility(View.GONE),500);
    });

}
```

This piece of code removes the button only in the item that has been clicked. How to solve this?

**EDIT**

```
private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
private Context mContext;

SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_single_row, viewGroup, false);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

boolean a;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    holder.likes.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        v.postDelayed(() -> holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE),500);

    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageButton button;

    SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.button = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to removed/hide only clicked button or every button else than that?

Comment: I want to remove buttons in all the items of recycler including the one i clicked.

Comment: Create a boolean variable with true, when a button is pressed set it to false and call notifydatasetchange. while you are assigning values to your widgets/fields check for that variable, if false then hide the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
private Context mContext;
private boolean isClick = true;

SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_single_row, viewGroup, false);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    holder.likes.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        v.postDelayed(() -> {
        holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isClick = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        },500);
    });

    if(isClick){
        holder.binding.llShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.binding.llShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageButton button;

    SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.button = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

    }
}
```

It's perfect answer for your question.

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: I need to hide only the button from all the items in recycler. arraylist.clear removes all the items in recycler

Comment: @raghhav Most Welcome.This answer is perfectly working can you give as mark answer? You mark answer code is not in format, missing bracket and may be it's work wrong in some times because view is not set any where as visible So,it's generate may be error and i provide you full adapter code.

Comment: @HardikTalaviya Thank you for your suggestion and show me my mistake. Next time i will be try better then you :) Every little mistake is an new success. Thanks for push me toward my success : )

Answer (score 1):

```
    private boolean isShow=false;
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {
        if(isShow){holder.button.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
    }

holder.likes.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        v.postDelayed(() -> isShow=true,notifyDataSetChanged();},500);

    });
    }
```

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I edited my question. arraylist.remove will remove the entire list right? I am not sure about it

Comment: okay then in your code just add notifyDataChanged(); after visibility gone and if it is not working then update me.

Comment: I need to remove buttons from all the items in recycler. notifyDataChanged() removes only in item that I clicked the button

Comment: check my updated answer its definitely work for you!!

Comment: @Niceumang Please first correct your lambda function. It's not formatted code missing the bracket.

Comment: @raghhav please check my answer it's helping you.

Comment: @Niceumang Sorry Bro. Good try! better luck for next time! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better that you make a boolean field in your model ( that you passed to the recyclerview) and check if it was true the button be visible and when it was false the button be invisible and when an item clicked you can make this boolean false for items and then using notifyDataSetChanged() to update all items view

i hope it help you (: